# .loc in pandas looking up a name in one column and seeing if it exists in another column

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

In Pandas, I'm trying to look up a string value of names in Column A and if it is the same value in Column B, I would like to put a 1 in Column C and 0 if it doesn't.

So, If I look up "Kyrie Irving" in Column A and it also in Column B, I would like to put a 1 in Column C and 0 in Column C if he doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are lookin for np.where i.e

```
df['colC'] = np.where(df['colA'] == df['colB'],1,0)
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, use `isin`:

```
df['ColC'] = df.ColA.isin(df.ColB).astype(int)
```

Comment: I misunderstood , I thought OP was looking for 'String' to appear anywhere in ColB not  where ColA and ColB equal on the same row.

Comment: Yeah, You are right , That is why I delete mine :-)

Comment: @GilO'Brien where you looking for where 'string' in ColA equals to ColB on the same row or if 'string' from ColA appears anywhere in ColB?

Comment: @ScottBoston I think in this case, I think either would work, because the string would equal and also appears in the ColB.

Comment: @ Bharath, what are you talking about?

Comment: @Bharath your code was exactly what I wanted, but Scott Boston's also worked because it also fit the parameters of what I was looking for. Why did you delete your code?

Comment: @Bharath, I'm new to this. Yours was the best answer for what I was looking for. Happy Thanksgiving!